# Which package has oowriter?

Tags: 16.04

I cannot find it in `apt-get`. I need it for converting .odt documents into PDF; would be great for .doc/.docx too

```
cd /path/to/directory
oowriter -pt PDF ./*.odt
```

Systems: Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`oowriter` is open office writer. Open Office is a 3rd party application (and that explains why you can not find it).

What you want is `lowriter`. Libre office is installed by default and that is the equivalent of `oowriter`.

---

By the way: you should have seen a warning when you use `oowriter`:

```
$ oowriter -pt PDF ./*.odt
No command 'oowriter' found, did you mean:
 Command 'lowriter' from package 'libreoffice-writer' (main)
oowriter: command not found
```

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
soffice --headless --convert-to pdf *
```

where using the application without a interface (`-headless`) and internally `lowriter -pt PDF *.odt`, which prints (`-pt`) to PDF all .odt files as proposed by Rinzwind

> libreoffice is a shell script that sets up the environment and passes the command line arguments to the soffice.bin binary.

Its manual at `man lowriter`.

Answer (score 0):

You can open .odt files with many programs: OpenOffice (obviously), LibreOffice, Calligra Office,AbiWord (from Gnome Office),Scribus, WPS Office, or online, with Zoho Docs, Google Docs (this one actually open it by convertion-on-the-fly to GDocs filetype).

odt=open document text. It is the native text file format of OpenOffice (and LibreOffice).

For best results, it would be wise to check file properties, see what program produced that file and open it with the same program. Many programs,even Microsoft Office, opens odt files by importing or converting it to proprietary formats. This action is lossy in most cases, in doesn't lose the text, but misinterprets some formats and pagination. Graphical elements interpretation ( like equations, charts, vector graphics) is a major concern.